# Webform: prepopulate fields through URL, "page not found"

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to prepopulate fields in a webform from the URL.  I'm using Webform 7.x-3.20.  I have a form named prepopulate. It has a field "First Name" which has the default value set to %get[first_name].  I have tried to prepopulate the field from the following URL:

```
http://localhost/test_site/?q=content/prepopulate?first_name=miranda
```

This results in a "page not found" error.  Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks in advance!

*UPDATE: I've figured out this happens because it is a rewritten URL (Pathauto).  Still don't know how to fix it, though.

Comment: Did you try using this URL: `http://localhost/test_site/?q=content/prepopulate&first_name=miranda`? You can't declare the start of the query string twice, after the first `?q=` you can append new arguments by using the ampersand character - `&` :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer.

It seems clean URLs are not enabled in your site. So here I'm giving the solution in both ways

Assuming that your **Field Key**  for *First Name* field is `first_name`

**If clean URLS not enabled.**

> `http://localhost/test_site/?q=content/prepopulate&first_name=miranda`

**If clean URLS enabled**

> `http://localhost/test_site/content/prepopulate?first_name=miranda`

I've tested this on my environment and works perfect. Hope this helps